Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined while inline editing Telerik Grid
I've enabled in-line editing on my Telerik grid. However, whenever I click on a cell, I get an error saying "cannot read property." After some investigation, I realized that the issue is caused by having a main form already created and using the Telerik grid inside that form. When editing is enabled, a new form is created every time I try to edit a cell, leading to a nested form error. I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've seen that someone else had a similar issue (Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined while inline editing Kendo grid) and got it resolved, but I'm not sure how their solution applies to my case.
I attempted to ignore the jQuery validation within my nested form and also tried detaching and reattaching the form, but that didn't help much.

The Kendo Grid does not render a form for editing by default. It seems that some kind of custom editor is being used. Can you provide some details on the exact implementation?
What I would do is to:

Check against the latest version. Maybe there is a bug in the older versions
Check for a similar issue here - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues.
Alter the configuration so that nested forms are not used, as this is a bad practice.
Contact Progress support and provide code snippets so they can investigate the issue more thoroughly.


In my project, the older version of Telerik Grid is being used, which is causing the nested form problem.
To fix this, instead of using the begin form, I made an ajax call to invoke my post method and removed the begin form from the page. After making these changes, everything was working as expected.
